A pure CSS solution for importing a fallback stylesheet if the browser does not support "prefers-color-scheme" media query
Say I have a code that loads a stylesheet conditionally:
@import url("light.css") (prefers-color-scheme: light);
@import url("dark.css")  (prefers-color-scheme: dark);

But what if:

the browser does not support the prefers-color-scheme media query,
JS is disabled and
light and dark stylesheets conflict with each other (dark scheme does not completely override the light one) so you can't simply put the light scheme on top without any conditional?

As you know, CSS does not support checking if a media query itself is supported. I have found one hacky solution but the method described there seems not to work in @import syntax so this did not work for me:
@import url("light.css") (no all and (prefers-color-scheme));

Is there no solution for this?

If the browser does not support prefers-color-scheme, it will only load the style-default.css:
/* default */
@import url("style-default.css");

/* dark theme */
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  @import url("style-dark.css");
}

/* light theme */
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  @import url("style-light.css");
}

